# Go further, faster with

Tags: commas

I'm having a debate with a colleague about whether a comma is needed in this phrase. I think it reads odd without a comma. From my understanding, 'further' is an adverb in this phrase, and 'faster' is an adjective. I know that adverbs can modify adjectives (in which case a comma would not be needed), but I think the meaning is lost if you don't have a comma in this phrase.

If anyone can clarify this for me, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What do you intend to say? That you can further and faster, or that you can go further in a faster manner?

Comment: That you can go further in a faster manner.

Comment: "Faster" is an adverb, too.

Comment: Without a comma, *faster* could modify *further*; with a comma, it would modify *go*. The better options would be: "Go further and faster" and "Go further, go faster".

Answer (score 1):

**It needs a comma.**

The word with only affects the immediately former word. And so;

> Go further faster with

infers that "further faster" is a normative term in some context. I doubt it is.

The phrase reads unnaturally; as if it should be a list of verbs. And is frustratingly vague without it being a sentence as with should also be attached with a proceeding word.

> Go further, faster with **stimulants?**

In this case further and faster become questionably comparatively different. (Oh no! Did I miss a comma there? Or maybe the word "and") And that is my other point.

It would work without a comma only in absence of "with" if it were:

> Go further faster

Comment: I have to disagree with at least your last point here. Looking at this phrase through the lens of advertising rhetoric, 

"GO FURTHER _FASTER_**,** WITH [the all-new Yugo/organized crime software/our employee underpayment strategy]" 

(whether _faster_ is italicized or not), conveys more clearly what the author would want a reader to intuitively receive: **1.** Concise statement to trigger an emotional engagement—in clever alliteration, **comma** (a new but related idea is coming next), **2.** Insinuation that _product X_ is the key to gratifying the triggered desire.